# In the story of the blind man from birth (John 9) did Jesus take clay and mix it with spittle on the Sabbath?

Tags: word-study

In the original language of the man born blind from birth (John 9) did Jesus actually take clay and mix it with spittle on the Sabbath?

Comment: Might help if you add some context to your question. Is there a reason to suspect otherwise? Do you have a particular concern about it?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you refer to the incident recorded in John 9, then we can proceed.  The short answer to the questions is, yes to all.  V1 says that the man was blind from birth (Greek "ek genets").  v6 says that Jesus spat on the ground and made clay/mud out of the spittle and put it on the man's eyes.  V14 clearly says "Now it was Sabbath during which day Jesus made the mud and opened his eyes." (my translation).

Why ask these questions?  Is there some dispute about this?